# Checkbox :checked detection with jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, checkbox, checked

I have a check box that will if checked send a gift as a monthly gift. If check box is unchecked the gift is a single gift.

What I have:

```
<div id="monthly-right">
    <input type="checkbox" name="level_autorepeat" id="level_autorepeat" value="false" /> Yes, automatically repeat this gift every year on this date.</div>
<div id="donation-length"></div>
```

What I need to display if checked:

```
<div id="monthly-right"><input type="checkbox" name="level_autorepeat" id="level_autorepeat" value="false" /> Yes, automatically repeat this gift every year on this date.</div>
<div id="donation-length">
    <input type=hidden name="sustaining.frequency" id="sustaining_frequency" value="monthly" />
    <input type="hidden" name="sustaining.duration" id="sustaining_duration" value="0" />
</div>
```

And back if unchecked

Comment: So do you actually want to see the inputs, or just add the hidden inputs that the user won't see?

Comment: Do you really want the radio button to change into a checkbox?

Comment: Just add the hidden inputs that the user will not see

Comment: @Matthew so basically you need this http://jsfiddle.net/vKLWA/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do

```
$('#check').click(function() {
    var type = $(this).is(':checked') ? "checkbox" : "radio";
    var input_r_or_c = $('<input />', {
        type: type,
        name: "level_autorepeat",
        id: "level_autorepeat",
        value: "false"
    });
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        var input1 = $('<input />', {
            type: "hidden",
            name: "sustaining.frequency",
            id: "sustaining_frequency",
            value: "monthly"
        });
        var input2 = $('<input />', {
            type: "hidden",
            name: "sustaining.duration",
            id: "sustaining_duration",
            value: "0"
        });
        $('#donation-length').append(input1).append(input2);
    } else {
        $('#donation-length').empty();
    }
    $('#monthly-right input').replaceWith(input_r_or_c);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vKLWA/1/

Comment: He's got to have a typo in his question, right?  What is the usage model for having two checkbox/radio buttons to make this work, and why would one change?  Your answer does exactly what his html suggests, but it just seems... bizarre.

Comment: @JeffB yes it's bizarre, but that's what he asked. If he intended another thing i will change my code :)

Comment: I understand.  I am not criticizing your answer, just wondering aloud to a fellow answer-er.

Comment: There was a typo guys, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

If these are hidden inputs, I would do this on the server side.  Otherwise, if javascript is disabled, the user will have no idea that the checkbox is not doing anything and may inadvertently make a single or reoccurring contribution.

Hiding and showing hidden inputs will not affect whether they are sent to the server on submit anyway.  You will need to actually delete them from the DOM, or move them outside of your current form.

So basically, always send the hidden inputs, but on the server side, ignore the frequency/duration unless the checkbox value is set.

If you still want to do it with javascript anyway, you would need to do this:

```
var freq = '<input type=hidden name="sustaining.frequency" id="sustaining_frequency" value="monthly" /><input type="hidden" name="sustaining.duration" id="sustaining_duration" value="0" />';

$('#monthly-right').on('change', '#level_autorepeat', function() {
   if($(this).is(':checked')) {
       $('#level_autorepeat').html(freq);
   } else {
       $('#level_autorepeat').html("");
   }
}
```

The other answers show you how to check if a checkbox is checked, but you really need to watch for when it changes using an `onchange` handler, which is done via `.on()`.  I attach the handler to the parent, and watch when the checkbox changes.  If the checkbox is checked, I add the frequency/duration code (stored in a variable) into the `div`, otherwise I clear the HTML in the div.  You could do this a number of ways, including keeping the contents in another div outside of your form, and moving/copying the contents into the div.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I understand totally regarding ths being done on the server side, unfortunately this has to be done on the client side so the user must have JavaScript enabled. I am going to try this and see if this works for me. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can check if your checkbox is 'checked' using jquery:

```
$('#your_checkbox_id').is(':checked');
```

Comment: How would it check if it's unchecked? I would like to say if checked show these if unchcked do not add these hidden inputs to form

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**`$('#checkBox').attr('checked');`**

(or)

**`$('#checkBox').prop('checked');`**

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
 $('#donation-length').hide();
 if ($('#level_autorepeat').is(':checked')){
     $('#donation-length').show();
 }
```